# how to show data on tableview

Tags: android

I created a simple SQLite database.
in database create a table table1,in table1 has two column. 
inserted tow data record.
i want to show table1 Data on tableview.
how do this?
thank for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you columns are fixed to 2,then take xml file otherwise create dynamic tableLayout and create each row programmatically.

see below example for dynamic creation of tableRows.

[see this](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/)